# Как программно вызвать окно в браузере(Определение геопозиции)

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!
Может кто подскажет как в javascript вызвать вот такое сообщение?
Или как проверить, разрешена или нет у пользователя геолокация?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это браузер запрашивает, из JS нельзя такое сделать, чтобы не обманывать пользователей. Попытайтесь запросить данные и получите это окно.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как-то узнать, разрешена или нет у пользователя геолокация?

Answer (score 0):

Геолокация совершается через Geolocation API

Что бы проверить, поддерживает ли браузер геолокацию, существует такая функция:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
   alert("Geolocation API поддерживается");
}else{
   alert("Geolocation API не поддерживается в вашем браузере");
}
```

Определить геолокацию пользователя можно так:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
   var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Когда вы начинаете пользоваться скриптом геолокации, браузер сам у вас спросит, можно ли её использовать. Вот пример: https://thedotproduct.org/experiments/geo/

Подробнее про геолокацию можно прочесть здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: Спасибо, но это я и так знал. Мне нужно понять, можно ли как-то узнать разрешена или нет у пользователя геолокация в настройках браузера.

Comment: На mozila.org есть пример "request for permition", но он не работает.

Comment: @Ilya189, можно при запуске создавать переменную равную `false`. А когда пользователь разрешает её, то той же функцией нахождение координат пользователя `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)` изменять её на `true`

Comment: Да это понятно, а как узнать до выполнения этой функции разрешена у него геолокация или? Мне просто надо выводить определенное сообщение пользователю, перед тем как у него появиться окно, в котором будет написано: "Сайт ... запрашивает разрешение на использование данных о вашем местоположении"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation Вот на этом сайте есть пример "Запрос на доступ к данным". Но там не очень понятно относится он только к mozile или ко всем остальным браузерам тоже. В любом случае, он не работает.

Comment: @Ilya189, ну какой же вы бом-бом. Когда пользователь заходит на сайт, создаётся переменная с `false`. Потом запускается функция `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {перменная = true}`. После этой переменной делаете вывод нужной надписи. Когда переменная станет `true`, выключаете эту надпись

Comment: Сами вы бом-бом. Мне нужно, вызывать определенное сообщение перед тем как появиться запрос "Сайт ... запрашивает разрешение на использование данных о вашем местоположении". А в вашем примере мое сообщение будет появляться только когда пользователь УЖЕ даст или не даст свое согласие на обработку данных о его геопозиции.  Тем более что функции работают асинхронно и не так-то просто передать значение переменной из function(position) в основную функцию.

Comment: @Ilya189, это вы бом-бом :) Ищите в интернете все функции геолокации